# When dividing resolutions in javascript i get NaN

Tags: javascript, division

Hello i was working on this script where is calculated the ratio of the resolution of the screen or an image. Whenever an image didn't have a normal resolution or i tried it with the view-port resolution it would be `NaN`.

**Example (y is an image) :**

```
y.offsetWidth / y.offsetHeight = NaN
```

I tried numerous ways on the internet to fix this but i couldn't does anyone know wow to?

Comment: `offsetheight` typo? Plus, i don't know any `offsetLength` property.

Comment: provide your full script code. what is offsetLength?

Comment: I'm sorry when typing this i was in a bit of a rush it is supossed to be offsetHeight and offsetWidth

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want is something like

```
y.offsetWidth / y.offsetHeight
```

As nicovank mentioned, there is no `offsetLength` property.

Comment: I'm sorry when typing this i was in a bit of a rush it is supossed to be offsetHeight and offsetWidth.

Answer (score 0):

you will get NaN whenever you try to do arithmetic calculation on something which are not number or cant be parsed to valid number. Here, both `y.offsetLength` and `y.offsetheight` are `undefined` (because no such properties in JS) and hence yields to NaN when you try to do divition operation on them. Use `offfsetHeight`  and `offsetWidth` instead.

Comment: I'm sorry when typing this i was in a bit of a rush it is supossed to be offsetHeight and offsetWidth.

Comment: One or both of the numbers are not legal number.  You have to check which one is causing the problem.